# PHP Session id cookie spoofing

Tags: php, security, session, cookies

I would like to know if i can prevent session id cookie malformation. Let's say I have a cookie with key *SESS* and value of *md73i54kj98ti0uf8dftps2fa3* which is a valid session id and corresponding file *sess_md73i54kj98ti0uf8dftps2fa3* exists in my session storage folder. If I modify value for key SESS cookie to be for example *foo* it will create new file in sessions folder with name *sess_foo*. How can I check that provided cookie sess id value is invalid so that I can call `session_regenerate_id` for example to set valid id and create appropriate file.

Also, I am wondering if someone hypothetically renames cookie sess id to real session of another user will he get control? are there ways around this?

Thank you.

**Update 1:** First problem can be solved with `session.use-strict-mode` ini directive. http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-strict-mode
Though it requires some extra steps when using with custom session handler. (my case).
But still what if changed session id matches real session id of other user? Should I use some kind of fingerprinting (user-agent + ip) or encrypt session data with combined key of (user-agent + ip)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For new session files being created, you already have the solution which is `session.use-strict-mode`.

But what about guessing another session id? You are totally right, *if* you can guess another valid id, you will be using that session, effectively impersonating its owner. After login, the session id is the only secret used by the user, equivalent to the userid+password *for the session*.

Why is this not a problem then? Because you can't reasonably guess another valid session id. Session ids are (should be) cryptographically random, and so long that you can't just guess one (more precisely, they have a lot of entropy). Standard solutions, like the one in PHP and most other programming languages or frameworks provide a reasonable level of security, but you should not implement your own session management (id generation, verification, etc.), unless you *really* know what you are doing and are aware of the security aspects.

In your example, the session id seems to consist of 26 lowercase letters and numbers. There are 26 different letters and 10 numbers, so the number of possible session ids are (26+10)^26 = 2.9 * 10^40. Say you can try one billion (10^9) ids every second, and your server has one million sessions at once (neither of this is realistic in any way). It would still take around 10^25 seconds (~ 3*10^17 years) to correctly guess a valid session id. Note that this is *way* more then the age of the universe. :)

Of course, for the reason above (session id = username+password for the session), you must protect the session id as much as you can, for example by only storing it in an httpOnly cookie, and never sending it in the URL, or clear text (but always using https, with the secure flag for the cookie, and HSTS headers sent, etc).